# Show that $x \in I $ : $y(x) \le y(a)exp(\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ a  interval with $a := inf(I) \in I. Let $ $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $y:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$differentiable  with $y'(x) \le f(x)y(x)$ for all $x \in I$.
Show that for $x \in I $ : $y(x) \le y(a)exp(\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$

Comment: Couldn't you just [thieve the proof from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Differential_form)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Just multiply differential inequality $y'(x)-f(x)y(x) \le 0$ by 
$e^{-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt}$ and then integrate from $a$ to $x$ for $x\in I.$

${\bf Edit:}$
Letting $k(x)=e^{-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt}\Longrightarrow$$k'(x)=-f(x)e^{-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt}=-f(x)k(x)$ (by the derivative of exponentiaal function and fundamental theorem of calculus). Also notice that $k(a)=1$. Now multiplying  $$y'(x)-f(x)y(x) \le 0$$ by $k(x)$ we get 
 $$y'(x)k(x)-f(x)k(x)y(x) \le 0,$$
from which we have $$y'(x)k(x)+k'(x)y(x) \le 0\quad\text{since}\quad k'(x)=-f(x)k(x).$$
Look at the LHS of this inequality, it is the derivative of the product $y(x)k(x)$. Thus we have $\big(y(x)k(x)\big)'\leq 0$, or we may write this as $\big(y(s)k(s)\big)'\leq 0$ with another variable $s$. Integrating with respect $s$ from $a$ to $x$ gives $y(x)k(x)-y(a)k(a)\leq 0$. This implies $y(x)k(x)\leq y(a)$ since $k(a)=1$. Substituting $k(x)$, we obtain $y(x)e^{-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt}\leq y(a)$. From which we arrive at the desired inequality.

Comment: Thank you ! So i have  $y'(x)e^{-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt} -f(x)y(x)e^{-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt} \le 0$. Then i should integrate like that ? $\int_{a}^{x}y'(x)e^{-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt}- \int_{a}^{x}f(x)y(x)e^{-\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt}dt \le0$ ? But how?

Comment: @Anna Saabel: the left-hand side of that inequlity becomes the derivative of product of $y(x)$ and that integral. Then you integrate.

Comment: Sorry i am completely stumped. Would you please be so kind and show me in  symbolic language what you mean.

Comment: I added the rest of the solution.